# run drupal2drupal that is configured in UI via drush

Tags: 7, migrations

Is there any way to run a drupal to drupal import with the Migrate module  that is configured in the UI via drush ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drush help --filter=migrate` provides a complete list of relevant commands.

**Examples**

`drush migrate-import Article`
Import new articles

`drush migrate-import Article --update`
Import new items, and also update previously-imported items

See official Drupal.org documentation for more info: https://www.drupal.org/node/1561820